# a Custom Filter for Domain and seperate Subfolder Match in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have an unusual pattern that I need to create a filter for.  I am trying to create a rolled up view for the following structure:

www.domain1.com/ 
and 
www.domain2.com/shop/en-gb/domain2

I want to create the filter that would show all the traffic in domain1 
and 
also show the traffic in domain2 but only in the domain2 subfolder.

Both domains share the same UA- Tag 
1. here is how I have tried to structure it: 
a. Include filter for domain1.com and domain2.com
b. Exclude filter for domain2.com for traffic not in subfolder <-- This is where I can't seem to get it working.

Would appreciate anyones guidance as to what approach I should take. 
Thanks

Comment: An include filter discards all data that does not match. As soon as you have an include filter for domain1.com all data from domain2.com is deleted. So that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a beautiful solution...

Filter 1 - custom filter type "Search and Replace" with search string "domain2.com/shop/en-gb/domain2" and replace string "domain1.com"

Filter 2 - include only traffic to hostname that contain "domain1.com"

Make sure you arrange the filters in the correct order, since they are processed in order.

Remember that filters can't be applied to your historical data; they can only be applied to data going forward.

Comment: Close but not cigar, since there is no filter field that has both hostname and page path (request uri is just the path, and hostname is just that). So you'd need an advanced filter, extract page path "/shop/en-gb/domain2" with a capture group and if present (see that checkmark on "Field 1 required" is checked) overwrite output field hostname with domain1.com. But as long as the original hostname is not required this is not a bad solution IMO.